# javascript a function to replace some words on my webpage

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript that replaces some words on my web page with other words. So  when the page loads, some words that I specify get replaced by something else

For example, if  "hello" is found replace with "hi"
if "one" is found replace with "two" etc.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does it need to be sequential or random?

Comment: TIL I learned that stackoverflow doesn't let you post let me google that for you links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="myDiv">
hello there my name is tom there hello there
</div>

<button onclick="replaceText()">Click me!</button>
```

With the JS:

```
function replaceText(){
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var theText = theDiv .innerHTML;

    // Replace words
    theText = theText.replace("word", "replace");
    theText = theText.replace("one", "fish");
    theText = theText.replace("tom", "drum");

    theDiv.innerHTML = theText;
}
```

You can insert a regular expression in the first parameter of the replace function if you want to avoid ruining tag markup (if for some reason you are replacing words like 'div' or 'strong').  But this function will work perfectly fine for plain text blocks.

Comment: innerHTML - you risk changing the nested tags and attribues

Comment: @Bob, thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated my answer to address that issue.

Comment: @Dave, I tested it, it works fine!  Put the function between the <script type="text/javascript"> tag in your head content, then the <div> in your HTML body somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

in jquery, add this to a script tag in your head tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p, div, span, li").each(function() {
   this.text(this.text().replace("word", "new word").replace("word2", "new word2"));
  });
});
```

you need to add to the list of tags any tags where you want text replacing, I've simply added the most common.

Comment: Sorry, I voted this down because he didn't specify Jquery.  There is absolutely no point loading the entire Jquery framework to run a function that is native to Javascript.

Comment: @Tom, even using a CDN file that is almost guaranteed to be cached on the user's machine? jquery is pure javascript so it seems a little harsh.

Comment: Late commenter, but I thought it was worth mentioning for anyone else who comes here. In my experience, this will remove nested tags and just leave the text so `<div><a href="">word</a></div>` would become `<div>new word</div>`.

Comment: @Mowgli not sure how you work that out. The only replacing is done on text() which is the innerText in raw js/DOM i.e. it ignores tags

Comment: That's exactly the problem. It extracts the text, ignores the tags, then reinserts the text. So if there is a nested tag with text inside, it will ignore the tag and not replace it upon replacement of the text. Example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MowgliB/vjj7jow1/).