# Change a Text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I want chance a Text with javascript i use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Neu = document.getElementById("thema")[0].value;
function Aendern () {
  document.all.meinAbsatz.innerHTML = Neu;
}
</script>
</head><body>
<p id="meinAbsatz">Text</p>
<input id="thema" type="text" value="Test Theme" />
<a href="javascript:Aendern()">chance theme</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If I click on "chance theme" the "Text" chance to "undefined"

Comment: Learn to code in english. Just a hint from a fellow guy speaking the same language as you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript a function to replace some words on my webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043471/javascript-a-function-to-replace-some-words-on-my-webpage)

Answer (score 4):

Method `getElementById()` returns a single element, not a set of elements. So there is no need in applying `[0]` to it. Also you should put the `Neu` initialization inside `Aendern()` function:

```
function Aendern() {
    var Neu = document.getElementById("thema").value;
    document.all.meinAbsatz.innerHTML = Neu;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RqgMb/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/FJr2t/

In the link above I made your code work.
Your two major problems are:

```
var Neu = document.getElementById("thema")[0].value;
```

Firstly, `getElementById('thema')` returns only one item, so you should drop the `[0]`.
Secondly javascript code in your head gets executed once, when loading. So this line once gets executed at the very beginning and reads the value the input element has then.
So you should also move it into your Aendern method.

P.S.: Putting your code in window.onload etc. is not neccessary in this case, but you should **definilty** look at it and do it.